# Android Room Insertion fired many times when pushing data to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-room

I'm working on an app that saves data to Firebase at the same time to Room database,

for working with Room, I used ViewModel and Repository and it works fine

```
notesViewModel.insert(note);
```

for working with Firebase I'm using a normal push, and also it works fine

```
mFBReference.child(Constants.CHILD_REF_VISITS_NOTES)
                .child(oneVisit.getVisitKey())
                .push()
                .setValue(note);
```

Now when I put them together in one method

```
void updateNotes(OneNote note) {

    notesViewModel.insert(note);

    mFBReference.child(Constants.CHILD_REF_VISITS_NOTES)
            .child(oneVisit.getVisitKey())
            .push()
            .setValue(note);
}
```

The Room insertion fired more than once, and every time I insert a new object, the number will be increased, but the firebase part works fine.

Is there any explanation for that?

**Update 1:**

I'm still trying , This problem just happens when I'm using Tab layout with Fragment (with or without ViewPager), but if I use just an Activity it works fine. The same thing if I put the code inside the activity or inside the fragment gives me the same problem.

Comment: Are you adding that object in a loop? Or is that code triggered also from other parts ofyour application?

Comment: There is no loop , I try it directly from the menu, also from dialog , always the same

Comment: I'm still trying , This problem just happens when I'm using Tab layout with Fragment (with or without ViewPager), but if I use just an Activity it works fine.

The same thing if I put the code inside the activity or inside the fragment gives me the same problem.

Comment: I think it would be useful to share more code, to see exactly what you are talking about,

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to add the following below code on top of Insert function in your Dao function

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

Comment: I already try it with and without , the same

Answer (score 0):

I think I will answer myself

After 3 days of trying get a solution finally I found the problem

I have 2 Activities (MainActivity , NotesActivity) and I'm working in the 2nd Activity, The problem was there is a ValueEventListener for the firebase in the 1st Activity also insert the object

[ValueEventListener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I69LM.png)

The solution just change it to addListenerForSingleValueEvent
Everything work ok.